# How to set MUI breakpoint values in KotlinJS

Tags: material-ui, kotlin-js

I am using https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin-wrappers/tree/master/kotlin-mui which is a KotlinJS wrapper around Material UI for React.

I am trying to port the following code to Kotlin:

```js
<Grid container spacing={3}>
  <Grid xs="auto">
    <Item>variable width content</Item>
  </Grid>
  <Grid xs={6}>
    <Item>xs=6</Item>
  </Grid>
  <Grid xs>
    <Item>xs</Item>
  </Grid>
</Grid>
```

The issue I am having is that I don't know how to set the value for the `xs` breakpoint.

Answer (score 0):

Okay apparently this can be done by creating extension properties:

```kotlin
inline var GridProps.xs: Any?
    get() = asDynamic().xs
    set(value) = asDynamic().xs = value
```

(https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin-wrappers/issues/1856)